# ReactiveCommand - subscribing to ThrownExceptions does not prevent app crash

Tags: c#, wpf, reactiveui

According to the documentation (https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/commands/#handling-exceptions), subscribing to `ThrownExceptions` should prevent the app from crashing. I have following code (I put command in code-behind for simplicity):

```
public partial class MainPage : ReactiveUserControl<MainPageViewModel>
{
    private ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> Test = ReactiveCommand.Create(() => throw new Exception("This will crash the app!"));

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        
        this.WhenActivated(d =>
        {
            Test.ThrownExceptions.Subscribe(ex =>
            {
               Log.Error(ex);
            }).DisposeWith(d);

            Test.Execute().Subscribe().DisposeWith(d);
            
        });
    }
}
```

The application still crashes, I don't know why?

Comment: ThrownExceptions doesn't prevent exceptions halting the application. Just reports they happened. The documentation is a bit ambigious about this point. https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/issues/1356 -- will update it with clearer documentation.

Comment: Ok I see, so I should probably use `Execute().Catch(...)`. The documentation is very misleading.